# What makes functional programming languages declarative as opposed to Imperative?

Tags: functional-programming, prolog, imperative-programming, declarative-programming

On many articles, describing the benefits of functional programming, I have seen functional programming languages, such as Haskell, ML, Scala or Clojure, referred to as "declarative languages" distinct from imperative languages such as C/C++/C#/Java. My question is what makes functional programming languages declarative as opposed to imperative.

An often encountered explanation describing the differences between Declarative and Imperative programming is that in Imperative programming you tell the computer "How to do something" as opposed to "What to do" in declarative languages. The problem I have with this explanation is that you are constantly doing both in all programming languages. Even if you go down to the lowest level assembly you are still telling the computer "What to do", you tell the CPU to add two numbers, you don't instruct it on how to perform the addition. If we go to the other end of the spectrum, a high level pure functional language like Haskell, you are in fact telling the computer how to achieve a specific task, that is what your program is a sequence of instructions to achieve a specific task which the computer does not know how to achieve alone. I understand that languages such as Haskell, Clojure, etc. are obviously higher level than C/C++/C#/Java and offer features such as lazy evaluation, immutable data structures, anonymous functions, currying, persistent data structures, etc. all which make functional programming possible and efficient, but I wouldn't classify them as declarative languages.

A pure declarative languages for me would be one which is comprised entirely of declarations only, an example of such a languages would be CSS (Yes I know CSS would technically not be a programming language). CSS just contains style declarations which are used by the HTML and Javascript of the page. CSS cannot do anything else besides make declarations, it cannot create class functions, i.e. functions which determine the style to display based on some parameter, you cannot execute CSS scripts, etc. That for me describes a declarative language (notice I did not say declarative **programming** language).

**Update:**

I've been playing around with Prolog recently and to me, Prolog is the closest programming language to a fully declarative language (At least in my opinion), if it is not the only fully declarative programming language. To elaborate programming in Prolog is done by making declarations which state either a fact (a predicate function which returns true for a specific input) or a rule (a predicate function which returns true for a given condition/pattern based on the inputs), rules are defined using a pattern matching technique. To do anything in prolog you query the knowledge base by substituting one or more of the inputs of a predicate with a variable and prolog tries to find values for the variable(s) for which the predicate succeeds.

My point is in prolog there are no imperative instructions, you basically telling (declaring) the computer what it knows and then asking (querying) about about the knowledge.  In functional programming languages you are still giving instructions i.e. take a value, call function X and add 1 to it, etc, even if you are not directly manipulating memory locations or writing out computation step by step. I wouldn't say that programming in Haskell, ML, Scala or Clojure is declarative in this sense, though I may be wrong. Is proper, true, pure functional programming declarative in the sense that I described above.

Comment: Where is @JimmyHoffa when you need him?

Comment: 1. C# and **modern** C++ are very functional languages.
2. Think of the difference of writing SQL, and Java to achieve a similar purpose (maybe some complex query with joins). you can also think how is LINQ in C# differs from writing simple foreach loops...

Comment: also the diffirence is more a matter of style than something clearly defined... unless you are using prolog...

Comment: One of the keys to recognizing the difference is when you're using an *assignment* operator, vs. a definition/declaration operator - in Haskell for instance there *is no assignment operator*. The behaviour of these two operators is very different and forces you to design your code differently.

Comment: Unfortunately even without the assignment operator I can do this `(let [x 1] (let [x (+ x 2)] (let [x (* x x)] x)))` (Hope you understood that, Clojure). My original question is what makes this different from this int `x = 1; x += 2; x *= x; return x;` In my opinion its mostly the same.

Comment: @ALXGTV You can indeed see functional programming as a superset of imperative programming. Your example with Clojure doesn't show reassignment; instead, it's an example of introducing new bindings with the same name (aka "shadowing"). The difference with imperative reassignment is that this effect is not seen outside the scope of the shadowing, whereas if you truly reassigned x, other parts of your function would see the change.

Comment: @AndresF.: By that definition, imperative programming can also be seen as a superset of functional programming. Several imperative programming languages allow for scoped identifier shadowing. I guess it's even simpler to program in FP-style within an imperative language than vice versa. Modern compilers often enough already employ such a transformation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_single_assignment_form

Comment: @phresnel Yes, it's roughly correct that imperative programming can also be seen as a superset of funcional programming. Indeed, both are equally powerful and can simulate each other. However, in practice it is easier to simulate the mutation/impurity from imperative languages by using a FP language, while simulating pure FP by using an imperative language is harder (because imperative languages do not enforce it, so they are at the mercy of the programmer). In this sense, FP is a superset of IP, while the converse is less true.

Comment: @phresnel *"Several imperative programming languages allow for scoped identifier shadowing"*: note that this isn't enough. They must not simply "allow" it, it must be mandatory, and they must also prohibit `x = 1; x += 1` in the same scope. Introducing new bindings is NOT the same as changing a reference to point to a new value!

Comment: @AndresF.: But an imperative programming language is not actually required to not default to constants. Just because most - if not all -  imperative programming languages default to mutable variables, this is not mandatory property of what makes an imperative language. Scala's on the edge here, with the lack of any default. Personally, I like the OCaml way, with default-const - and would love default-const in C++ or C# (my C++-fingers already default to const :D).

Comment: @AndresF.: Regarding your second reply: True, it's really not the same - reminds me of the discussions about how a single `const` in C++ may designate pointer _or_ pointee (or pointee pointee (or pointee³)). One question: Do you mean it's easier to simulate an IPL within _pure_ FPL code, or within impure FPL-code?

Comment: @phresnel It's not required but it's often the default, and when it's not, immutability is not mandated. Scala, OCaml, etc, have plenty of features from FP (enough that they are often considered FP languages to some degree!), so I think that's what you're noticing :) Making effects explicit also matters; you can encode the effects from imperative languages and make them explicit in FP, but it's harder to go the other way (how can you say in an imperative, impure language "this has these and only these effects"? You can, but it's more a "gentleman's agreement" than something actually enforced.

Comment: @phresnel In practice, designers of modern imperative languages have realized a lot of the good stuff from FP makes sense, and they are incorporating it into their languages, so the distinction gets blurred. Still, as Erik Meijer once said -- somewhat tongue in cheek, so take it with a grain of salt -- ["mostly functional" programming does not work](http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=2611829). In other words, there are benefits to "going all the way" which cannot be easily achieved by cherry picking features from pure FP languages :)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You seem to be drawing a line between declaring things and instructing a machine. There is no such hard-and-fast separation. Because the machine that's being instructed in imperative programming need not be physical hardware, there is much freedom for interpretation. Almost everything can be seen as an explicit program for the right abstract machine. For example, you could see CSS as a rather high level language for programming a machine that primarily resolves selectors and sets attributes of the thus-selected DOM objects.

The question is whether such a perspective is sensible, and conversely, how closely the sequence of instructions resembles a *declaration* of the result being computed. For CSS, the declarative perspective is clearly more useful. For C, the imperative perspective is clearly predominant. As for languages as Haskell, well…

The language has specified, concrete semantics. That is, of course one can interpret the program as a chain of operations. It doesn't even take too much effort to choose the primitive operations so that they map nicely onto commodity hardware (this is what the STG machine and other models do).

However, the way Haskell programs are written, they frequently *can* sensibly be read as a description of the result to be computed. Take, for example, the program to compute the sum of the first N factorials:

```
sum_of_fac n = sum [product [1..i] | i <- ..n]
```

You can desugar this and read it as a sequence of STG operations, but far more natural is to read it as a *description of the result* (which is, I think, a more useful definition of declarative programming than “what to compute”): The result is the sum the products of `[1..i]` for all `i` = 0, …, n. And that is far more declarative than almost any C program or function.

Comment: The reason I asked this question is that a lot of people try to promote functional programming as some new distinct paradigm completely separated from the paradigms of C/C++/C#/Java or even Python when in reality functional programming is just another higher level form of imperative programming.

Comment: To explain what I mean here you are defining sum_of_fac but sum_of_fac is pretty much useless on its own unless that is what your hole application does, you need to use the result to compute some other result which eventually builds up to achieving a specific task, the task which your program was designed to solve.

Comment: @ALXGTV Functional programming *is* a very different paradigm, even if you're adamant about reading it as imperative (it is a very broad classification, there is more to programming paradigms than that). And the other code that builds on this code may be read declaratively too: For example, `map (sum_of_fac . read) (lines fileContent)`. Of course at some point I/O gets into play but as I said, it's a continuum. Parts of Haskell programs are more imperative, sure, just like C has a sorta-declarative expression syntax (`x + y`, not `load x; load y; add;`)

Comment: Functional programming is indeed a very different paradigm from the paradigms used in C/C++ etc. however it is a superset of Imperative programming. When I was learning Clojure, I didn't see much which would make it non-imperative, it just provides a higher level abstraction to certain imperative details.

Comment: @ALXGTV Your intuition is correct: declarative programming "just" provides a higher level of abstraction over certain imperative details. I'd argue this is a big deal!

Comment: @ALXGTV: Functional programming is a sub-set of imperative programming (not a super-set). Essentially, you take imperative programming and remove the ability to modify state. Of course in practice this makes it unusable for any practical purpose; so you're forced to re-introduce the ability to modify state in a different form (e.g. monads); which means that in practice it ends up being equivalent to imperative programming (just with different syntax) and neither a sub-set nor super-set.

Comment: @Brendan I don't think functional programming is a subset of imperative programming (nor is immutability a mandatory trait of FP). It can be argued that in the case of pure, statically-typed FP, it's a superset of imperative programming where effects are explicit in the types. You know the tongue-in-cheek assertion that Haskell is "the world's finest imperative language" ;)

Answer (score 22):

The basic unit of an imperative program is the *statement*.  Statements are executed for their side effects.  They modify the state they receive.  A sequence of statements is a sequence of commands, denoting do this then do that.  The programmer specifies the exact order to perform the computation.  This is what people mean by telling the computer *how* to do it.

The basic unit of a declarative program is the *expression*.  Expressions do not have side effects.  They specify a relationship between an input and output, creating a new and separate output from their input, rather than modifying their input state.  A sequence of expressions is meaningless without some containing expression specifying the relationship between them.  The programmer specifies the relationships between data, and the program infers the order to perform the computation from those relationships.  This is what people mean by telling the computer *what* to do.

Imperative languages have expressions, but their primary means of getting things done is statements.  Likewise, declarative languages have some expressions with semantics similar to statements, like monad sequences inside Haskell's `do` notation, but at their core, they are one big expression.  This lets beginners write code that is very imperative-looking, but the true power of the language comes when you escape that paradigm.

Comment: This would be a perfect answer if it contained an example.  The best example that I know of to illustrate declarative vs. imperative is Linq vs. `foreach`.

Comment: Are SQL (e.g. `INSERT INTO relation (x) VALUES (3);`), HTTP (e.g. `PUT /path HTTP/1.1 {"x": 3}`), HTML (e.g. `<!DOCTYPE html><html lang=""><title>x</title>`), and CSS (e.g. `h1 { font-size: 3rem; }`) declarative programming or imperative programming?

Answer (score 7):

The real defining characteristic that separates declarative from imperative programming is in declarative style you are not giving sequenced instructions; at the lower level yes the CPU operates this way, but that's a concern of the compiler.

You suggest CSS is a "declarative language", I wouldn't call it a language at all. It's a data structure format, like JSON, XML, CSV, or INI, just a format for defining data that's known to an interpreter of some nature.

Some interesting side effects happen when you take the assignment operator out of a language, and this is the real cause for losing all those step1-step2-step3 imperative instructions in declarative languages.

What do you do with the assignment operator in a function? You create intermediate steps. That's the crux of it, the assignment operator is used to alter data in a step-by-step fashion. As soon as you can no longer alter data, you lose all of those steps and end up with:

**Every function has only one statement, this statement being the single declaration**

Now there are many ways to make a single statement look like many statement, but that's just trickery, for instance: `1 + 3 + (2*4) + 8 - (7 / (8*3))` this is clearly a single statement, but if you write it as...

```
1 +
3 +
(
  2*4
) +
8 - 
(
  7 / (8*3)
)
```

It can take on the appearance of a sequence of operations which can be easier for the brain to recognize the desired decomposition the author was intending. I often do this in C# with code like..

```
people
  .Where(person => person.MiddleName != null)
  .Select(person => person.MiddleName)
  .Distinct();
```

This is a single statement, but shows the appearance of being decomposed into many - notice there are no assignments.

Also note, in both above methods - the way the code is actually executed is not in the order you immediately read it in; because this code says what to do, but it does not dictate *how*. Note the simple arithmetic above is obviously not going to be executed in the sequence it's written left to right, and in the C# example above those 3 methods are actually all re-entrant and not executed to completion in sequence, the compiler in fact generates code that will do what that statement *wants*, but not necessarily *how* you assume.

I believe getting used to this no-intermediate-steps approach of declarative coding is really the most difficult part of it all; and why Haskell is so tricky because few languages truly disallow it like Haskell does. You have to start doing some interesting gymnastics to accomplish some things that you would typically do with the aid of intermediate variables, such as summation.

In a declarative language, if you want an intermediate variable to do something with - it means passing it as a parameter to a function which does that thing. This is why recursion becomes so important.

`sum xs = (head xs) + sum (tail xs)`

You can't create a `resultSum` variable and add to it as you loop through `xs`, you have to simply take the first value, and add it to whatever the sum is of everything else - and to access everything else you have to pass `xs` to a function `tail` because you can't just create a variable for xs and pop the head off which would be an imperative approach. (Yes I know you could use destructuring but this example is meant to be illustrative)

Comment: The way I understand it, from your answer, is that in pure functional programming, the entire program is made up of many single-expression functions, whereas in imperative programming functions (procedures) contain more than one expression with a defined sequence of operation

Comment: 1 + 3 + (2*4) + 8 - (7 / (8*3)) it is actually multiple statements/expressions, of course it depends on what you view as a single expression. To sum it up functional programming is basically  programming without semicolons.

Comment: @ALXGTV the difference between that declaration and an imperative style is that if that mathematical expression were statements, it would be *imperative* that they be executed as written. However because it is not a sequence of imperative statements but rather an *expression* that defines a what you want, because it doesn't say *how*, it's not imperative that it be executed as written. Therefore the compile can reduce the expressions or even memoize it as a literal. Imperative languages do this too, but only when you put it in a single statement; a declaration.

Comment: @ALXGTV Declarations define relationships, relationships are malleable; if `x = 1 + 2` then `x = 3` and `x = 4 - 1`. Sequenced statements define instructions so when `x = (y = 1; z = 2 + y; return z;)` you no longer have something malleable, something the compiler can do in multiple ways - rather it's imperative the compiler do what you instructed there, because the compiler can't know all side effects of your instructions so it can't alter them.

Comment: You have a fair point.

Answer (score 6):

I know I'm late to the party, but I had an epiphany the other day so here it goes...

I think comments about functional, immutable and no side-effects miss the mark when explaining the difference between declarative vs imperative or explaining what declarative programming means. Also, as you mention in your question, the whole "what to do" vs "how to do it" is too vague and really doesn't explain either.

Let's take the simple code `a = b + c` as a basis and view the statement in a few different languages to get the idea:

When we write `a = b + c` in an imperative language, like C, we are assigning the *current* value of `b + c` to the variable `a` and nothing more. We aren't making any fundamental statement about what `a` is. Rather, we are simply executing a step in a process.

When we write `a = b + c` in a declarative language, like Microsoft Excel, (yes, Excel *is* a programming language and probably the most declarative of them all,) we are *asserting a relationship* between `a`, `b` and `c` such that it is always the case that `a` is the sum of the other two. It's not a step in a process, it's an invariant, a guarantee, a declaration of truth.

Functional languages are declarative as well, but almost by accident. In Haskel for example `a = b + c` also asserts an invariant relationship, but only because `b` and `c` are immutable.

So yes, when objects are immutable and functions are side-effect free, code becomes declarative (even if it looks identical to imperative code,) but they aren't the point. Nor is avoiding assignment. The point of declarative code is to make fundamental statements about relationships.

Answer (score 0):

You are right that there is no clear distinction between telling the computer **what** to do and **how** to do it.

However, on one side of the spectrum you almost exclusively think about how to manipulate memory. That is, to solve a problem, you present it to the computer in a form like "set this memory location to x, then set that memory location to y, jump to memory location z ..." and then somehow you end up having the result in some other memory location.

In managed languages like Java, C# and so on, you don't have a direct access to the hardware memory anymore. The imperative programmer is now concerned with static variabes, references or fields of class instances, all of which are to some degree absractions for memory locations.

In langugaes like Haskell, OTOH, memory is completely gone away. It is simply not the case that in

```
f a b = let y = sum [a..b] in y*y
```

there must be two memory cells that hold the arguents a and b and another one that holds the intermediate result y. To be sure, a compiler backend could emit final code that works this way (and in some sense it must do so as long as the target architecture is a v. Neumann machine).

But the point is we don't need to internalize the v. Neumann architecture to understand the above function. Nor do we need a contemporary computer to run it. It would be easy to translate programs in a pure FP language to a hypothetical machine that works on the base of the SKI calculus, for instance. Now try the same with a C program!

> A pure declarative languages for me would be one which is comprised entirely of declarations only

This is not strong enough, IMHO. Even a C program is just a sequence of declarations. I feel we must qualify the declarations further. For example, are they telling us what something **is** (declarative) or what it **does** (imperative).

Comment: I didn't state that functional programming was no different from programming in C, in-fact I said that languages such as Haskell are at a MUCH higher level than C and offer much greater abstraction.